# Azure CosmosDB AutoScaling Using Code/Automation

Tags: c#, azure-cosmosdb, azure-automation

Is it possible to autoscale the CosmosDB throughput using either c# or Azure Automation? Please provide a sample example.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Storage is automatically scaled. Here is the code to change the throughput automatically

```
//Fetch the resource to be updated
Offer offer = client.CreateOfferQuery()
                  .Where(r => r.ResourceLink == collection.SelfLink)    
                  .AsEnumerable()
                  .SingleOrDefault();

// Set the throughput to 2500 request units per second
offer = new OfferV2(offer, 2500);

//Now persist these changes to the database by replacing the original resource
await client.ReplaceOfferAsync(offer);
```

See more here: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/cosmos-db/set-throughput

HTH

Comment: This seems great! i must have missed it as it was posted 2 days ago. Thank you!